# I have tried using Plugins to remove 72K comments with no success

Tags: comments, customization

I have tried a lot of plugins that say they will remove all the comments with NO luck.

I am still showing a number of 72,037 comments, but I no longer can see the actual comments themselves. And, it's showing them all in 'Pending' with 103 in trash.  This site has been inactive for a couple years and I am just helping out getting it cleaned up for use again. How do I get that number to STOP showing up if I really don't have the comments. And, if I do where are they hiding?  Help please.  I am the Admin for the site in question.

Comment: Do you have access to your MySQL database?

Comment: what kind of plugins do you use? woocommerce? bbpress? anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information on your question, it's hard to confirm where your issue is coming form. However, here's one sure way of finding and deleting all of your comments from your website:

1. Make sure you have a working **database backup** before proceeding.
2. Go to your WordPress database via phpMyAdmin, you should see a list of all of your tables
3. Check both the `wp_comments` and `wp_commentmeta` tables and select the *Empty* option:

   [image]

Confirm the action and all of the comments will be removed from your database. You should not see any more comments (pending, trash, published, etc).

Comment: due to policies of wordpress.com woocommerce and EDD store transaction logs as comments in a special comment type. Since core do not handle well comment types which are not the ones it knows, you can get a mismatch between the number of comments in the UI and the ones in the DB. Deleting all "comment"datalike you suggest is a risky thing to do.(not sure what will be the impact on bbpress and bodypress)

Comment: I added a database backup notice, just in case something goes wrong when deleting the data (e..g like accidentally clicking other tables). The comment count is also stored in the `comment_count` column in the post table.